# Google oAuth 2.0 authentication uri parameter "display" is not working

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am using google oAuth 2.0 for login in my website. I want to show the google server login page as a pop-up window. I serachedfor this on google developer page and get

[display authentication uri parameter](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#authenticationuriparameters)

i used the display parameter as :

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=xxxx&
      display=popup&
      state=xxxx&
      response_type=code&
      client_id=xxx&
      login_hint=xxx
```

But i am not getting the popup window for google server login. Can anybody please tell me what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the popup yourself and set this as the URL. The display parameter tells Google that the page is being rendered in a popup.
If you want an easier way to create popup and do the whole flow, better option to do all this with a few lines is to use Google+ signin. https://developers.google.com/+/